# How do you display boolean values in a cell of React-Data-Grid?

Tags: react-data-grid

Pretty simple issue, I'd like to display boolean values in my react-data-grid.  I honestly don't care how it's displayed: Checkbox, Radio, text...  I just want it to appear so I can edit it.

I'd rather not convert my data to all strings, then have to reconvert them back but that may be the only way.

This is a related issue that was just simply closed: https://github.com/adazzle/react-data-grid/issues/722

There's also a similar question: [Using CheckboxEditor with react-data-grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44895261/using-checkboxeditor-with-react-data-grid) asked yesterday and completely silent.

Does anyone have any way to show and edit boolean values in React-Data-Grid, or should I be looking elsewhere.

Comment: It seems that the only way, at least until the react-data-grid team solves it, is to convert it to string: https://github.com/adazzle/react-data-grid/issues/882

Answer (score 0):

Since it's Boolean you can have a dropddown. I don't have a demo to show, but you can get the idea of what to do by looking at the following example.
[Link](http://adazzle.github.io/react-data-grid/#/examples/built-in-editors).
There see the logic behind "Issue Type" Column.